# Using Quill Editor in React App to Send Email. How to apply the styles

Tags: reactjs, react-quill

I am using the [Quill React Editor](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-quill) to generate rich text. This html generated shows fine in my App as the Quill editor has its custom style for bigger font size etc but this html needs to sent as EMAIL. How can I ensure the email has all the custom styles intact for the recipient that look fine in Quill editor.

Or is there a way to use inline style? or any solution for me?

Another option: I can use the some styles in the style tag before the quill component. So the app uses those styles but when html is extracted it still uses only the class name, how can I use the inline styles or a way to keep the styles intact. Example in link: [Styling a Component with style tag](https://levelup.gitconnected.com/using-the-html-style-tag-to-style-a-react-component-b3203e8eb0d9)

TIA